# Conditional Randomization

Tags: random, conditional-statements

Imagine there is a list of elements as follow:

```
1a, 2a, 3a, 4a, 5b, 6b, 7b, 8b
```

Now we need to randomize it such that not more than 2 "a"s or 2 "b"s get next to each other. For instance the following list is **not** allowed because of the 2nd, third and fourth elements:

3a, **7b, 8b, 5b**, 2a, 1a, 5b, 4a

How can we write write an efficient code without generating many random sequences and many triad comparisons?

Comment: Is [**1a, 2a**, 5b, 3a, 6b, 4a, **7b, 8b**] a *valid* sequence? (i.e. "not more than 2" - is `2` included or not?)

Comment: What is the desired *distribution*? *Uniform* among all the possible series?

Comment: By "2" I meant the allowed frequency for occurance of two similar letters, e.g. 1a, 4a and not 1a, 3a, 4a.

Comment: How many a's and b's are there? (Or more accurately, is the maximum number less than around 30?)

Comment: @rici   yes it is less than 30. (sorry for the late response!)

Comment: @user3640761: I'll fill in some pseudocode or maybe some python tomorrow if I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Create two bins, one for the a's and one for the b's.  Pick from a random bin and record the bin.  Pick a second number from a random bin.  If the bin is not the same as before just record the bin.  If the bin is the same as before then force the next pick to be from the other bin.  Carry on forward, only forcing a bin when you have two picks in succession from the same bin.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't actually work; sometimes you will end up having to throw out an entire sequence because it cannot be continued. But if you only discard sequences when they become impossible (i.e. one bin is empty and the other one has more than two residents), then you will introduce a bias into the selection algorithm.

Comment: You could tweak the algorithm to preferentially pick from the larger bin when it has a choice.  That would reduce the number of times you needed to reject an uncompletable partial solution. You are right that some possible question are unsolvable: 1a, 2a, 3a, 4a, 5a, 6a, 7b, 8a for example.

Comment: Yes, you could but that won't fix the bias.

Comment: Given that there are unsolvable versions of the problem, then it is impossible to provide a universal solution.

Comment: Sure, the problem only has a solution if both element types account for at least one-third of the elements (roughly; actually, the minimum is ceil((n-2)/3), I believe). But that determination can be made before we start generating any sequence, so a correct algorithm either produces an unbiased random sequence or reports impossibility.

Comment: Your ceil((n-2)/3) is correct.  1a, 2a, 3b, 4a, 5a is legal, with 4/5 a's and 1/5 b's.  The 1/3 is an approximation only valid for large lists.

Comment: given that the minimum needs to be an integer, 1 is not a *terrible* approximation of one-third of 5; it's not the closest integer, true, but it is one of the adjacent ones. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that:

- There are only two kinds of element, `a` and `b`, and
- There aren't "too many" of either kind (say, less than 30) or that you're willing to use a bignum package.

The basic idea is to (conceptually) first construct a valid sequence of `a`s and `b`s, and then randomly assign the actual elements to the `a`s and `b`s in the sequence. In practice, you could do both of these steps in parallel; every time you add an `a` to the sequence, you select a random `a` element from the set of such elements not yet assigned, and similarly with `b` elements.

The (slightly) complicated part is constructing the valid sequence without bias, and that's what I'm going to focus on.

As is often the case, the key is to be able to count the number of possible sequences, in a way which leads to an enumeration. We don't actually enumerate the possibilities -- that would take really a long time for even moderately long sequences -- but we do need to know for every prefix how to enumerate the sequences starting with that prefix.

Rather than produce the sequence element by element, we'll produce it in chunks of one or two elements of the same kind. Since we don't allow more than two consecutive elements of the same kind, the final sequence must be a series of alternating chunks. In effect, at every point except the very beginning, the choice is whether to select one or two of the "other" kind. At the beginning, we must select one or two of either kind, so we must first choose the starting kind, after which all the kinds are fixed; we merely need a sequence of 1's and 2's -- representing one element or two elements of the same kind -- with the kind alternating at each step. The sequence of 1s and 2s is constrained by the fact that we know how many elements there are of each kind, which corresponds to the sum of the numbers in the even and odd positions of the {1,2}-sequence.

Now, let's define `f(m,n)` as the count of sequences whose even and odd sums are `m` and `n`. (Using CS rather than maths rules, we'll assume that the first position is 0 (even) but it actually makes absolutely no difference.) Suppose that we have 6 `a`s and 4 `b`s. There are then `f(6,4)` sequences which start with an `a`, and `f(4,6)` sequences which start with a `b`, so that the total count of valid sequences is `f(6,4)+f(4,6)`.

Now, suppose we need to compute `f(m,n)`. Assuming `m` is large enough, we have exactly two options: choose one of the `m` elements of the even kind or choose two of the `m` elements of the even kind. After that, we will swap even and odd because the next choice applies to the other kind.

That rather directly leads to the recursion

```
f(m, n) = f(n, m-1) + f(n, m-2)
```

which we might think of as a kind of two-dimensional fibonacci recursion. (Recall that `fib(m) = fib(m-1) + fib(m-2)`; the difference here is the second argument, and the fact that the argument order flip-flops at each recursion.

As with Fibonacci numbers, computing the values naively without memoization leads to exponential blow-up of recursive calls, and a more efficient strategy is to compute the entire table starting from `f(0,0)` (which has the value 1, obviously); in essence, a dynamic programming approach. We could also just do the recursive computation with memoization, which is slightly less efficient but possibly easier to read.

For now, let's just assume that we've arranged for the computation of `f(m,n)` to be suitably fast, either because we've prebuilt the entire array of possibilities up to the largest values of `m` and `n` we will need, or because we're using a memoizing recursive solution so that we only need to do the slow computation once for any given `m,n`. Now let's construct the random sequence.

Suppose there are `na` `a`-elements and `nb` `b`-elements. Since we don't know whether the random sequence will start with an `a` or a `b`, we need to first make that decision. We know there are `f(na,nb)` valid sequences which start `a` and `f(nb,na)` valid sequences starting with a `b`, so we start by generating a random non-negative integer less than `f(na,nb) + f(nb,na)`. If the random is less than `f(na,nb)` then we'll start with `a`-elements; otherwise we'll start with `b` elements.

Having made that decision, we'll proceed as follows. We know what the next element kind is and how many elements remain of each kind, so we only need to know whether to select one or two elements of the correct kind. To make that choice, we generate a non-negative random integer less than `f(m, n)`; if it is less than `f(n, m-1)` then we select one element; otherwise we select two elements. Then we swap the element sets, fix the counts, and continue until `m` and `n` are both 0.